# in mathematica how to get fully expanded answer for rational system of linear equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I define a matrix.

```
m= { {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}}
```

Then i solve the system of linear equation.

[image]

It gives correct result. But same thing if i do using non-integral coefficients such as re-defining m as

```
m = {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1/N[Sqrt[3], 3], 0}}
```

It fails. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: works for me: `{{x -> -4. z, y -> 6. z}}`  The rounding is caused by your low precision spec on `N`, is that your concern?

Comment: Yup, it rounds the rational answer to integral, how to get answer upto 3 decimal places at least.

Comment: Use the exact or at least higher precision numerical `Sqrt` and apply `N` to the solve result.

Comment: It is interesting, if you do `z/(-2 + N[Sqrt[3], 3])` you get `-3.7 z`, so it seems `Solve` is not correctly carrying through the precision..

Comment: I had same issue in Mathemtica 10.1.0